# AWSのEC2でセキュリティグループを作成したいのですけども、エラーが出ます。

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

こんばんは。お世話になります。

AWSのEC2でセキュリティグループを作成したいのですけども、エラーが出ます。
「セキュリティグループの作成」ボタンを押して、
セキュリティグループのルールのインバウンドのタイプをMYSQL/Aurora、
プロトコルをTCP、ポート範囲を3306、ソースはカスタムでセキュリティグループIDを入れました。

作成ボタンを押すと「セキュリティグループの作成中にエラーが発生しました。」と出て、
下にエラーメッセージが下記のように出ました。

```
You have specified two resources that belong to different networks. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound; Request ID: 2d062039-24c8-45d0-b3d5-947d2442f05c)
```

セキュリティグループを作成したいので、解決法をご教授願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージの通りなんでしょうが。

> プロトコルをTCP、ポート範囲を3306、ソースはカスタムでセキュリティグループIDを入れました。

実際に入れている値をスクショとって、共有すると回答が早いと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
結局、EC2やVPCやサブネットなどをすべて削除してやり直すことにいたしました。

ありがとうございました。